# Some questions about curved spacetime QFT

Tags: qft-in-curved-spacetime

I'm reading Winitzki's Introduction to Quantum Effects in Gravity and I get some questions:

1. In the remark of section 8.3, Page 105. When we calculate the energy-momentum tensor in Rindler space, because
   $$
   <0_R|(\partial_u \hat{\phi})^2|0_R>
   $$
   is singular on the future horizon at $u=0$ so the Rindler vacuum is a singular state. Here why should the energy-momentum contain the term $\partial_u \hat{\phi}$? $u$ is the coordinate in Minkovski spacetime and I think the EMT in Rindler spacetime should be in terms of $\partial_{\tilde{u}} \hat{\phi}$
2. In equation (8.45) the delta function $\delta (0)$ should the volume of the V. But it comes from 
   $$
   \int d\tilde{u}
   $$
   in the equation (8.38) and I think it doesn't make sense to interpret it as volume which should be
   $$
   \int dx
   $$

3.About the Hawking effect in section 9.1, page 117. It is said that a non-external black hole formed as a result of collapse need not to consider the left-moving(outgoing) modes $u$ on the past light-like infinity. Also other lectures about Hawking effect also expand the field on the past light-like infinity only in terms of ingoing modes $v$, and on the future light-like infinity in terms of outgoing modes $v$. I get confused about that. They are modes and they are not particles. If I expand the field both in terms of $v$ and $u$ then what is going wrong?

They may be some naive questions. Thank you! :)

Comment: Most people try to ask three separate questions if they have three separate questions. If you post three new questions you can then delete this one (you can delete it since no one has responded)